# Loss of Ethernet on Ubuntu 20.04 and the entire Network Interface

Tags: drivers, 20.04, ethernet

I recently was given an XPS 9500 as my work computer. I initially installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as a dual boot with windows. Things seemed to work fine, and I'm pretty confident that I didn't have an issue getting wired internet via an Ethernet cable to my works Thunderbolt docking station.

Over the holidays I ended up installing the pop OS desktop and when I returned to work I no longer am able to connect to the ethernet. In fact, I can't even find any ethernet nic related card. The output from lspci is:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 10th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 05)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller
00:13.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 06fc
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake HECI Controller
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b8 (rev f0)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06be (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO UART Host Controller #0
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 068e
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f95 (rev a1)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
03:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
03:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
03:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
04:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
38:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
6c:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5260 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
6d:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
```

and there is no reference to ethernet. In the Network portion of Settings, it just has some VPN options and doesn't look at all like I remember it.

I have spent a few hours Googling, and it seems like some people had issues when they installed pop OS (but again, I only installed the desktop as far as I know). For example here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/597315/pop-os-ubuntu-20-04-no-network-interfaces-anymore . nmcli didn't change anything for me.

In Windows, the ethernet comes through the thunderbolt connection fine, just as I remember it initially doing with Ubuntu 20.04. When the ethernet is working in windows, the associated network adapter appears to be RealTek USB GbE Family Controller #2 (as far as I can tell, it only lists a (1) Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) and (2) Killer(R) Wi-fi Wireless Network Adapter in windows before plugging in the thunderbolt docking station, afterwards the RealTek bit appears). I tried installing the RealTek r8125 driver for kernel up to 5.6 and followed the readme instructions but that didn't change anything.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: If you added POP repositories, you'll quite possibly have changed your system from Ubuntu, to Pop OS, as package tools upgrade to the *higher* packages, which allows downstream distros to use this for their advantage (use upstream packages & not have them be replaced; by artificially giving them a higher package number..).  It's unclear to me if you're still using Ubuntu 20.04 in your question.

Comment: @guiverc To be honest it is unclear to me AS. I ended up with the Pop Os transition just because it offered a nice way to switch between the NVIDIA graphics card and the on board intel to conserve battery. I thought I was just installing the desktop extension. Under the Settings/Details/About it is still listed as Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. If it was full Pop Os would this appear as something else?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and had no issues. I'm new to Thunderbolt docking stations in general, after the reinstall, when I plugged in the docking station a message popped up to allow the docking station to connect. I have a feeling that I was an idiot and I just didn't notice that message when I had installed Pop Os before, and the entire issue might have been that I didn't give permission to the Thunderbolt device before. In part, I suspect this because if I am not connected to the docking station, nmcli still does not list any ethernet device which was what was really throwing me off before. That part still seems odd to me.